In LWC, does it support continuous query of APEX until the result is obtained?
Scenario description:
After the button is triggered, customer A's data is created in salesforce, and Apex pushes the data to a third-party system (including the Account ID). After a long period of processing, the third-party system creates contact data through the REST API and associates it with the customer. At this time, I need to obtain the corresponding contact data created by the third party based on the Account ID.
What is a good solution to achieve this?
Solutions I have tried:

Platform Event, which work well on desktop, but no support for mobile devices.

JS setInterval, but I checked the log and only called findContactsById once.


setInterval solution code example:
Apex
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> findContactsById(String accId) {
    return [SELECT Id,Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accId];
}

JS
this.searchInterval = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        const result = await findContactsById({ accId: acc.Id});
        if (result.length > 0) {
            this.contacts = result;
            clearInterval(this.searchInterval);
        } else {
            console.log('No contacts found, retrying...');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error retrieving contacts: ' + error.body.message);
        clearInterval(this.searchInterval);
    }
}, 10000);


clearInterval as name suggests aborts the setInterval. If you remove the clearInterval from try block then the polling should work fine. Platform events would be an ideal solution; if you prefer that then maybe using cometd would work. For us pub/sub from salesforce did not work in LWC on communities and cometd worked.
